# sending mail message php

Tags: php, sql, email, echo

i just want to send the order content fetching the result in my database.
But when i echo it, it displays it on my php page. i dont want it.
I want the content to only appear in the email when the user receive it.

This is my code.

```
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
$addresses=$row3['email'];
$to = $addresses;

$subject = "Order confirmed by Home and decor";



// message
$message = '


<html>
<body>
<table width="500" height="215" border="0">
<tr>
<th width="238" height="211" scope="col"><h1 align="left">Order # 1234</h1></p></th>
<th width="10" scope="col"></th>
<th width="243" scope="col"><p><img src="file:///D|/Programs/xampp/htdocs/images/sitelogo.PNG" width="224" height="68" align="right"></p></th>
</tr>
</table>

<table width="500" height="215" border="0">
<tr>
<th width="181" height="211" scope="col"><p align="left">Ship To:</p>
<p align="left"><?=$row3['first_name']?></p>
<p align="left"><?=$row3['address_1']?></p>
<p align="left"><?=$row3['city']?></p></th>
<th width="80" scope="col"></th>
<th width="40" scope="col"></th>
<th width="181" scope="col"><p align="left"></p>
<p align="right">Bill To:</p>
<p align="right"><?=$row3['first_name']?></p>
<p align="right"><?=$row3['address_1']?></p>
<p align="right"><?=$row3['city']?></p>
</th>
</tr>
</table>

<table width="500" height="94" border="0">
<tr>
<th height="43" scope="col"><div align="left">Order Date:</div></th>
<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th scope="col"><div align="right">Shipping Method:</div></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th width="126" height="43" scope="col"><div align="left">1/11/13</div></th>
<th width="433" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th width="103" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th width="156" scope="col"><div align="right">BEAST!</div></th>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="500" height="88" border="1">
<tr>
<th width="48" scope="col">Item</th>
<th width="264" scope="col">Product Name</th>
<th width="68" scope="col">Quantity</th>
<th width="92" scope="col">Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table width="500" height="227" border="0">
<tr>
<th height="43" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th scope="col">Subtotal:</th>
<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th height="43" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th scope="col">Tax:</th>
<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th height="43" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th scope="col">Shipping:</th>
<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th height="43" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th scope="col">Discount:</th>
<th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th width="40" height="43" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th width="278" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
<th width="68" scope="col">Grand Total:</th>
<th width="96" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
</table>
<p align="right">&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>



';



// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";





$headers .= 'From: Order reminder <lol@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";



mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


}
```

Echo is when you want to call something out right. I dont want it to echo, i just want to make the content appear in the email without echoing it.

Comment: $message is only uses in the mail, in the above code, so should not be seen - this is a .php page?

Comment: so in the $message, even if i echo the result after fetching the fields, it wont display in the php page but it will display in the email sent?

Comment: see Jim or jack below i misread your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't echo your variables, concatenate them into the string.  i.e.

```
$message = "Some text ".$foo." some more text';
```

Not:

```
$message = "Some text <?=$foo ?> some more text';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this PHP Documentation for Turn on output buffering.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what are the sally wrong shorttag doing right in the middle of your message content.

```
<?= ?>
```

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use) for more information about shorttags

I'd just replace all those things from

```
<?php
    $message '...
        <p align="left"><?=$row3['first_name']?></p>
```

to

```
<?php
    $message '...
        <p align="left">'.$row3['first_name'].'</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Heredoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax for this:

```
$message =<<<EOM
<html>
<body>
...
<table width="500" height="215" border="0">
<tr>
<th width="181" height="211" scope="col"><p align="left">Ship To:</p>
<p align="left">{$row3['first_name']}</p>
<p align="left">{$row3['address_1']}</p>
<p align="left">{$row3['city']}</p></th>
...
EOM;
```

It's recommended to apply `htmlspecialchars()` on `$row3` first though:

```
$row3 = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $row3);
```

*This assumes you will not use `$row3` later in your code*